# PHP load CSS based on $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] fails in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome

I'm trying to load a CSS file from a directory based on a dynamic filename generated with PHP $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. The idea being $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] is queried and matched to a client id. That id is used in the CSS filename i.e. "1.css" or "5.css" in the html head depending on the client id.

This method seems to be working in Safari and Firefox but just loads ".css" in google chrome on my mac.

Since PHP is server-side I can only assume it's the $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] which is not being picked up via Chrome.

Two questions. Why? And - since this is a serious issue - what are my alternatives for dynamically writing the .css filename?

Thanks!

```
// Set client ID for session
$id_client_sql = "SELECT id FROM client WHERE url='".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."'";
$id_client_res =  mysqli_query($dbConnect, $id_client_sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbConnect));

$client = mysqli_fetch_array($id_client_res);
$id_client = $client['id_client'];
```

Then -

```
$display_block .= '<link  rel="stylesheet" href="'.$id_client.'.css">'; //etc...
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using. I can't think of any reason HTTP_HOST wouldn't be populated.

Comment: @Michael Unless it is for some bizarre reason a HTTP/1.0 client...

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your selection not with HTTP_HOST.

Comment: @Michael Neither?! I'm finding this one quite puzzling...

Comment: Info is missing. How would this work? Do you have multiple sites running on the same code, and do you want to load specific stylesheets, based on which site is visited (i.e. what the value of `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is? If so, show the code that does that.

Comment: @Tom What does `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` show you under Chrome?

Comment: @Michael bare with me...

Comment: PLEASE escape every single piece of foreign data used directly in a query - including `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Can you show the value of the raw `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable when it doesn't work?

Comment: @CodeCaster Multiple sites, yes. The code that does that is above more or less. The display block is part of header.php and the idea is the HTML is rendered with the appropriate id in the css filename.

Comment: Wow! - OK Thanks @Michael. Stupidly I hadn't resolved for http://domain.com or http://www.domain.com. the database only contains "domain.com" so $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] wouldn't work with www in front. Will do a simple string replace before query and should be sailing!

Comment: Solved - `$client_url = str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` instead in Chrome.  I know this one was solved already but I encountered a blank `HTTP_HOST` in Chrome and trying `SERVER_NAME` instead fixed it.

Comment: THanks @Marvin. Will see if I have any more problems before I make that change. Currently the code doesn't identify browsers - I'd prefer to try and maintain a common solution for all. (tough!)

Comment: What I did was check to see if `HTTP_HOST` is empty.  If so then I use `SERVER_NAME`